# Simple Java OAuth example

Tags: java, rest, ssl, oauth

I am trying to integrate Stripe (payment processor) with a Tomcat/JSP application. They have a library for most of it except the initial OAuth2 connection.

Not being a Java/Net programmer, I am having trouble getting my head around implementing the  REST api in Java.

Their documentation does not cover Java very well but the cURL examples "should" be easy to work from.

Basically I need to simulate this:

```
curl -X POST https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token \
-H "Authorization: Bearer sk_test_123123123123" \
-d code=AUTHORIZATION_CODE \
-d grant_type=authorization_code
```

Then I need to parse the JSON response.

Can anyone provide me with a code fragment to get me over this? Thanks

Comment: Do you want to implement an OAuth server ([RFC 6749](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749)) or just want to make a [token request](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-4.1.3) as an OAuth client application?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a [Java OAuth Library](http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/java/core/) to handle the OAuth portion of the code.